# Query tables returned by query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to query a column in all tables whose names i get from a query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT [COLUMN_NAME] FROM (SELECT FKTABLE_NAME FROM @temp_table)
```

This gives a syntax error though, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is the data format the same in all of the potential tables? If it isn't, you'll have a tough time doing this at all.

Comment: No it isn't.. I actually only need to select one column though that they all share in common.. I've updated my original question

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't right. I'll have a look and try again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data in all of the possible tables is the same format (ie the same data types in the same order), you could do something like this (probably not the most efficient solution in the world, but a solution):

```
    create table #FK_Names(tab varchar(50))
    insert into #FK_Names values ('#tab1')
    insert into #FK_Names values ('#tab2')

    create table #tab1(id int)
    create table #tab2(id int)

    insert into #tab1 values (1)
    insert into #tab1 values (2)
    insert into #tab1 values (3)
    insert into #tab2 values (4)
    insert into #tab2 values (5)
    insert into #tab2 values (6)
    /*You want the part following this comment */

    create table #temp (id int)
    declare tabCursor insensitive cursor for select * from #FK_Names
    declare @tabName varchar(100)
    open tabCursor
    fetch from tabCursor into @tabName
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin   
        declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
            set @cmd ='insert into #temp select * from ' + @tabName
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @cmd
        fetch next from tabCursor into @tabName
    end
    close tabCursor
    deallocate tabCursor

    select * from #temp
```

Comment: I get errors when i try and run this code. It says incorrect syntax near 'cursor'.

Comment: Corrected version on now - my bad. No @ required for cursor names. The part of the answer above the comment creates some test data so I could test it for you.

Comment: Still getting errors.. To make sure: `declare tabCursor insensitive cursor for select * from #FK_NAMES` should be `declare tabCursor insensitive cursor for select FKTABLE_NAME from @temp_table`, correct? Also, how is #temp getting filled?

Comment: Yes, your edit is right for your case. 
#temp gets filled by executing the SQL statement created in the variable @cmd in the loop (insert into #temp select [column_name] from )

Comment: Ah yeah of course! Don't know how I missed that.. This works now thanks!